# systemd - define a service without ExecStop and be able to stop it without "fail"

Tags: systemd, services, hadoop

I am with CentOS 7, and I want to start Kafka standalone producer (File Connector) as a service. The command is:

```
/opt/kafka/bin/connect-standalone.sh /opt/kafka/config/connect-standalone.properties /opt/kafka/config/connect-file-source.properties
```

And, obviously, it has no stop command. Normally, I just <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> to stop it as a foreground process.

But when I test, I found very tedious to open several terminal console session to run several processes (Zookeeper, Kafka server, Kafka producer, Storm jar, etc.) so I change Zookeeper and Kafka server as service, which have their `stop` script. But in this case, no.

I tried `systemctl start kafka-producer` and `systemctl stop kafka-producer`, but the service entered `failed` status, and is not stopped. I had to delete the service, reload the daemon, and switch to manual again.

`kafka-producer.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Kafka Producer
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/opt/kafka/bin/connect-standalone.sh /opt/kafka/config/connect-standalone.properties /opt/kafka/config/connect-file-source.properties
Restart=on-abort

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Anyway to manipulate a service without `ExecStop` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you normally stop the process with CTRL+C from your shell, a `SIGINT` (interrupt signal) is sent to the process. (see [`man signal`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html))

When systemd tries to stop a process without `ExecStop=` it sends a `KillSignal=` which defaults to `SIGTERM` (terminate signal), waits for a response from the process, and if it fails to stop within a deadline, systemd sends a `SIGKILL` which simply forcefully ends the process.  systemd's behaviour can be modified with `KillSignal=` (see [`man systemd.kill`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.kill.html)).

In your case, I would try adding `KillSignal=SIGINT` to emulate the CTRL+C you usually use in the shell.  You know your process catches and responds to this signal, but we don't know how it responds to SIGTERM.

```
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/opt/kafka/bin/connect-standalone.sh /opt/kafka/config/connect-standalone.properties /opt/kafka/config/connect-file-source.properties
KillSignal=SIGINT
Restart=on-abort
```

Answer (score 0):

Having HDP 2.6.4 with Kafka 0.10.1 installed, the script reported

```
/usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/kafka/bin$ ./connect-standalone.sh
USAGE: ./connect-standalone.sh [-daemon] connect-standalone.properties
```

a property to run as daemon by using the option `-daemon`.

Would this something feasible for you?